# Visual Studio Code doesn’t resolve implicit index files anymore?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code editor has stopped resolving the implicit `index.js`-files.

So eg. if I type `import {  } from './utils';` and place the cursor between the brackets and hit CTRL+SPACE, I get no intellisense on the exports from `./utils/index.js`-file. But if you add `index`, like `import {  } from './utils/index';` I do. It use to work without index, but now it doesn’t.

Anyone know if this a bug, a “feature”, or maybe a setting? Maybe I screwed something up?

I noticed this change in version 1.24.0 I think, now I run 1.28.2 and still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the moduleResolution in the tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json can help resolving this

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

Further reading: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution

Answer (score -1):

So typical! I’ve had this issue for months trying to resolve it in different ways. But just after posting this, I happened to make a change in my `jsconfig.json`-file and I found a `compilerOptions.moduleResolution` setting. Changing it to `"node"` fixed the problem...

That is;

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```